rootDir in testRegex in Jest config
In jest.config.ts, this matches no test files:
testRegex: ['<rootDir>/src/__tests__/.+\\.ts$']

While this does:
testRegex: ['src/__tests__/.+\\.ts$']

But it can also match the files from the nested projects like foo/src/__tests__/, which should be avoided, so root directory is essential for the expression to work correctly.
Is it possible to use rootDir path with testRegex without resorting to globs and testMatch?
